# Is it possible to use free_y in likert plots from likert r package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making nice plots using the `likert` package. the problem I encounter is that I haven't been able to make the heights of the plots depend on the number of likert scales.

If I have just one likert scale the result is ugly. I want the be abley to influence the height.

```
plot(likert(likert_5),type="heat",text.size=2.5)
```

this is the result:

[image]

and I want it to be something like this:

[image]

I tried the `facet_grid()` function of the `ggplot2` package, but it didn't work.

```
plot(likert(likert_5),type="heat",text.size=2.5)+facet_grid(scales = "free_y", drop = FALSE)
```

I must admit I am very new to `ggplot2` (and the package `likert` that depends on `ggplot2`), so the solution could turn out to be simple, but it really would help me a lot! Many thanks in advance.

Here's a reproducable example:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 4, 5)), .Names = "Variable", row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

df[,1] <- factor(df[,1], levels=c(1,2,3,4,5))

library(likert)
plot(likert(df),type="heat",text.size=2.5)
```

Comment: Have you tried resizing your plot window? Something like `free_y` changes the min and max values of the y-axis, but has nothing to do with the physical size of the plot.

Comment: I will give it a try! Are you sure it won't be possible to solve this problem programmatically?

Comment: Well sure it is... if you're saving the plot, you can specify the dimensions of the file. For display purposes you could try `+coord_fixed()`.

Comment: when adding +coord_fixed() it indeed changes the dimensions, but it flips the plot as well. When adding both +coord_fixed() and coord_flip() nothing happens. No changed dimensions and nog flipping. strange.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe there's already a `coord_flip()` defined internally. If you post a minimal example, I'd take a closer look.

Comment: Gregor, I added an example. Will that help you? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you're using the plot. In an interactive R session, your best bet is to resize the plotting window. I don't know how to resize the plot window programmatically in RStudio. If you're not using RStudio <strike>you should start using it!</strike> you can give height and width to `dev.new()`, e.g.,

```
dev.new(height = 1, width = 5)
plot(likert(df),type="heat",text.size=2.5)
```

If you're saving the plot, then whatever method you're using has height and width arguments, and this is where a programmatic approach makes the most sense. E.g.,

```
lplot <- plot(likert(df),type="heat",text.size=2.5)
ggsave("myplot.png", plot = lplot, width = 5, height = 1)
```

If you really want to modify the plot object itself,  we can edit the class of the coordinate attribute of the plot.

```
lplot <- plot(likert(df),type="heat",text.size=2.5)
lplot <- lplot + coord_fixed() # the default ratio of 1 looks good to me
#  but you can adjust it
class(lplot$coordinates) <- c("flip", class(lplot$coordinates))
print(lplot)
```

Comment: thank you so much!! It works very well. Now I have to find a solution about the big area of white space around the plot, but I guess I will figure that out.

Comment: @user1983395 Is there a reason you can't resize the plot window??? When I view Stack Overflow on my wide monitor, there's white margins... if I want them to go away I narrow the browser window. It's a standard way to interact with stuff.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. I was not clear about my final purpose. I put the plots, programmatically, into a word document (using ReporteRs package). The result is much white space in the document. But I think I can figure that out. Bottom line is: The plots look much better now with your solution!

Comment: I've never used that package before, but whatever function you're using to add the images probably takes height and width arguments (`ReporteRs::addImage` and `addPlot` both do), in which case that's all you need!

Comment: Thanks this is a nice solution